# docker command from the running docker / process

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker

In my setup, we launch docker containers using Amazon ECS Infrastructure. I know the EC2 Machine (host) where the docker is running and can see the container id.

With this information, is there anyway I can figure how the docker command that was used to run the container?

For e.g.

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
d02739ac9a59        dockerhub.amazonaws.com/something   "/script.sh"   32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes                                    ecs-production
cf47d404c6ba        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:v1.7.1                                      "/agent"            About an hour ago   Up About an hour    127.0.0.1:51678->51678/tcp   ecs-agent
```

I have this. I want to know, what was the

```
sudo docker run <various configuration parameters>
```

Comment: You can run `sudo docker inspect <container-id>` to see the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [this discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/get-docker-run-command-for-a-container/4679):

> You wont get the exact full command including volumes, port mappings and other options passed to docker run from docker inspect in a single line.
>   You will have to extract this information from the json returned from docker inspect and frame the full docker run command used.

For instance, [this gist suggests](https://gist.github.com/miracle2k/c85b7b077fdb8d54bc89):

```
# Convert an existing docker container into a "docker run" command line.
# 
# This is useful when trying to debug containers that have been created
# by orchestration tools.
#
# Install jq: stedolan.github.io/jq/

function format_run() {
    cid=$1

    json=$(docker inspect $cid 2>&1)

    # parse container info
    entrypoint=$(  echo $json | jq -r '.[0].Config.Entrypoint | join(" ")'             )
    envvars=$(     echo $json | jq -r '(.[0].Config.Env | [" -e " + .[]] | join(""))'  )
    image=$(       echo $json | jq -r .[0].Image                                       )
    cmd=$(         echo $json | jq -r '.[0].Config.Cmd | join(" ")'                    )

    echo "docker run --entrypoint $entrypoint $envvars $image $cmd"
}
```

That is still incomplete: you would need as well:

- `{{.VolumesFrom}}`
- `{{.Volumes}}`
- `{{ .HostConfig.links}}`
- and many others

See [**nexdrew/rekcod**](https://github.com/nexdrew/rekcod) more a more complete solution.

Comment: Thank you!. That was extremely helpful.